# Spring Boot viewResolver not working - not mapping to given location

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[image]

I am developing spring boot application for learning.

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

I have configured my view resolver as given above. And below is the API endpoint for page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePage(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

But when i hit this api, i am unable to get a response. I get 404
and error i get on console is
 `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServle`

How can i fix this ?

Comment: you've still not asked a question yet

Comment: Have you tried putting your jsp in the location indicated by the error message: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`?

Comment: I am definately missing something here because i have tried putting my jsp on every possible location even in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`

Answer (score 2):

for people struggling with issues like this - the Spring Boot documentation states [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) that JSPs are not supported when running in embeddable servlet container - i.e. when using JAR packaging.

when using WAR packaging, the suggestion given in the answers here should work - but check that in the final WAR there is a directory at root: WEB-INF/views, with your JSPs

Answer (score 0):

the view path is wrong `/WEB-INF/view/` instead `/view/`

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

or you can use the application.properties located in `/resources/` instead

and add these properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

**important:** the jsp views should be in `/resources/` directory