# Spring MVC Cannot configure views' path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a project that uses Spring Boot 2.2.5 (Spring version 5) - here is a link to a [bare minimum project](https://github.com/Taisho/mvn-spring-app-01) demonstrating my problem. In all the tutorials I followed they claim views' path can either be configured inside `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

or inside [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) derived class like this:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.jsp("classpath:/", ".jsp");
}
```

or like this:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(final ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}
```

None of which work in my case. Spring will always serve .jsp files from `src/main/webapp` and from nowhere else in spite of my configuration or lack of it. No other file types will be served from that directory, not even HTML.
Some tutorials claim that when not configured Spring will serve anywhere from

```
src/main/resources/static
src/main/resources/public
src/main/resources/resources
src/main/java/META-INF/resources
```

I am yet to see this.

CSS and Javascript files will be served from `src/main/resources` but only if I have this in my MVC configuration:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
}
```

Configuring this from `application.properties` doesn't work

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/
```

In relation to this are there other special folder names like `classpath:` that can be used? I tried `webapp:` but it doesn't seem to be expanded

UPDATE: I thought for a moment that maybe subclassing [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html) is to blame since it acts like @EnableWebMvc. Subclassing [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) brought the following error. Placing @EnableWebMvc solves it.

```
    An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:369)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager, org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService, org.springframework.validation.Validator)'
```

I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477312/spring-boot-viewresolver-not-working-not-mapping-to-given-location) that JSP view are not supported inside embedded servlets. What a nice feature! Anyway I don't thing this is related to my problem.

I would like to stick to JSP and avoid Thymeleaf  as my project is based on React. I will create MVC pages in order to be Search engine friendly, though but I will figure this out along the way.

Here is a screenshot of my project's layout

[image]

Comment: JSP will only work in a WAR not in JAR. It will only be resolved from a place accesible by the servlet container. As it isn't actually Spring (or a third party framework) resolving the files. More on this is also explained in the reference guide , [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). But if you only use React, why even bother with a JSP. just write a static index page and let that serve your app. No need for a JSP at all.

Comment: I will deploy the app in WAR. I am testing it with `mvn spring-boot:run`. For the JSP part - I need to catch URLs that would be legitemate URLs in the frontend and "render" them on the server in order to make them visible for search engines

Comment: Still you don't need a JSP for that, you can do that in a controller. Also what URLs could that be, as everything is served by React, so you will have local routes (using an anchor) and those aren't visible on the server. The only thing you would need to do is forward that to the general `index.html` with the proper anchor-tag and that is perfectly doable in a controller (or even web-filter). So still non need to use a JSP.